# Plesk 11 named.conf Failed

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, named-conf

I am using PSA for my web and mail hosting with CentOS.

When I reboot the server and when I start PSA, it says an error occurred: `service named failed`.

I did a little research and the named.conf file doesn't exist anywhere on my servers. I can't download bind because Plesk already downloaded it and I can't run bind too.

My error log

```
Jan 21 17:59:18 host named: _default/209.165.46.in-addr.arpa/IN: file not found

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone isathens.gr/IN: loading from master file isathens.gr failed: file not found

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone isathens.gr/IN: not loaded due to errors.

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: _default/isathens.gr/IN: file not found

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone 209.165.46.in-addr.arpa/IN: loading from master file 

209.165.46.in-addr.arpa failed: file not found

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: zone 209.165.46.in-addr.arpa/IN: not loaded due to errors.

Jan 21 18:01:38 host named: _default/209.165.46.in-addr.arpa/IN: file not found
```

isathens one domain

Comment: Have you looked in your log files?

Comment: You need to contact Plesk or your reseller.

Comment: @pauska I contacted plesk but nothing....

Comment: @Ladadadada Log files shows logs from two hours earlier and also my hosts can't get any mail.

Comment: anyone??Nothing?? Please this is very URGENT

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

From your log I would conclude that multiple zone files were accidentally removed or corrupted for unknown reason. Try running `/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/dnsmng --update domain.com` for each domain you host - it should regenerate zone files. I am not sure it will fix all problems as I cannot tell size of damage.

P.S.
Just for reference - Plesk runs exactly the same Bind as shipped by your OS vendor.

Comment: No nothing... my sites are also down as my cp

Comment: "Sites are down" sounds quite ambiguous. You can check whether the Bind is your only problem by including your site names in hosts file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) - it is /etc/hosts on Linux and %SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows. If you can see your sites this way, then you at least know you need to repair Bind and not something else.

Answer (score -1):

Are you running your own nameservers or using externally hosted ones?

If you aren't running your own, remove bind9.  You do not need it.

If you are running your own nameservers, stop doing that and get external hosting for your nameservers.  Practically all registrars will give you at least simple hosting for free.

Comment: I think Plesk runs a customized version of BIND..

Comment: I am running my own nameservers and get external hosting isn't an option.